# How create a custom Spinner toolbar dropdown in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I need to add a custom Spinner drop-down to my action bar.In main-activity  I'm using following code.

```
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Spinner mToolbarSpinner;
    private List<SpinnerNavItem> mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems;
    private BaseAdapter mArrayAdapter;

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

       /*Setup a Spinner*/
    mToolbarSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_toolbar);
    /*Manage the spinner*/
    mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();

    mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Local", R.drawable.deviceonline,"device namne1","port",false));
    mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems.add(new SpinnerNavItem("My Places", R.drawable.deviceonline,"device name2","port2",false));

    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems);

    mToolbarSpinner.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

when I run the project I’m getting following output

[image]

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options for you:

- First, you can override method `toString()` of class `SpinnerNavItem` to return what you want to display.
- Second, you can override method `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` of `ArrayAdapter` to display exactly what you want.

  - `getView()` to display text of current selected item on `Spinner` (current displaying text of `Spinner`)
  - `getDropDownView()` to display text of each item in popup drop-down list of `Spinner`

    ```
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
    mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            SpinnerNavItem currentItem = mToolbarSpinnerNavigationItems.get(position);
            // remember to inflate custom layout for spinner item
            // then set anything you want here
            // remember to use convertView.findViewById(), not just findViewById()

            // this is an example
            // inflate layout
            convertView = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
            // get view
            TextView tvText1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            // set content
            tvText1.setText("Text to display");
            // return
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // implement the same way as getView() method
        }

    };
    ```

Comment: can explain how to use convertView.findViewById() in side this method?

Comment: It's same as `findViewById()` you used before in your code.

Comment: what id I need to find ? I tried to find the id of support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml but i can't.Please give direction..

Comment: In `support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml`, there is only one `TextView` with `android:id="@android:id/text1"`. Hence you can find it by using `android.R.id.text1` and then set text for it.

Comment: problem is support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml have only one TextView that is true but It doesn't have any ID.Please look at the images. http://www.yogile.com/ye2oaqrp/06410884l/share/?vt=lXM5On7

Comment: Try this one: `findViewById(android.R.id.text1);`. Its `id` is `text1` already defined by Android framework in `android.R`.